# update single column of Stub Entity in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have `Book` and each book can have multiple `Chapter`. Each of the `Chapter` has a single audio file. How can I update single row of chapter sub entity?

This is my model:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Int64 ISBN { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookID { get; set; }


    public string bookName { get; set; }

    public string bookAuthor { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal bookPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int ChapterId { get; set; }

    public string chapterName { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public Int64 ISBN { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

In Create `ActionResult` I add new `Chapter` by create new object from Chapter model and add it using `book.Chapters.Add()`

```
for (int i = 1; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    var mfile = Request.Files[i];

    if (mfile != null && mfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mfile.FileName);
        Chapter _bChapter = new Chapter()
        {
            chapterName = fileName,
            chapterLink = BookDir +  mfile.FileName

    };
        book.Chapters.Add(_bChapter);
        mfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(_bChapter.chapterLink));


    }
}
```

in Edit ActionResult I get new audio using `HttpPostedFileBase`

```
public ActionResult Edit(Book book, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)  
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //do some File operation to save audio in server folder

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(book);
}
```

But I dont know how to save new uploaded audio to chapter sub entity

Comment: How look your _chapter sub entity_? Can you describe more what you want achieve?

Comment: @m.wiśnicki i upload new audio file and upload it to my host,i want to add uploaded file path in chapterName propery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `Chapter`, first find related chapter by using `SingleOrDefault` method, next edit `chapterName` property and call `SaveChanges()` method, like this:

```
using (var context = new YourDbContext())
{
    var result = context.Chapter.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ISBN == book.ISBN);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.chapterName = @"/root/my/audios";
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
using (var context = new YourDbContext())
{
    var result = context.Chapter.Where(b => b.ISBN == book.ISBN).ToList();
    if (result.Any())
    {
        foreach(var chapter in result)
        {
           chapter.chapterName = @"/root/my/audios";
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so now what if we have 6 chapter and user update only chapter 2 and 5

Comment: You can get collection where you edit only these 2 chapters, when you save changes basically you update only these 2 modified chapter.

Comment: thanks again but as i say i get list of new files with HttpPostedFileBase . i should loop through Chapters and also HttpPostedFileBase  ,how can i do it with only single for each?